# Object assignment in Vue.js method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods

I have a Vue component in which I select a specific value from an array of objects then attempt to copy some fields from that value into Vue data

```
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Add Item</h4>
    <form @submit.prevent="addItem(item.Code)">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ItemCode">Code</label>&nbsp;
            <select
              id="ItemCode"
              v-model="item.Code"
            >
              <input
                v-model="item.Code"
                type="hidden"
              >
              <option
                v-for="part in PartCodes"
                :key="part"
              >
                {{ part }}
              </option>
            </select>
   .
   .
   .
    </form>
  </div>
```

where the data is

```
  data() {
    return {
      item: {},
      parts: [],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    PartCodes: function () {
      return [...new Set(this.parts.map(p => p.Code))];
    },
  },
  created() {
    let uri = '/parts';
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      uri = 'http://localhost:4000/parts';
    }
    this.axios.get(uri).then(response => {
      this.parts = response.data;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    addItem(selectCode) {
      let uri = '/items/create';
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        uri = 'http://localhost:4000/items/create';
      }
      let selectPart = this.parts.filter( obj => {
        return obj.Code === selectCode;
      });

      this.item.Description = selectPart.Description;
      this.item.Cost = selectPart.Cost;
      this.item.Price = selectPart.Price);

      this.axios.post(uri, this.item)
        .then(() => {
          this.$router.push({name: 'QuoteIndex'});
        });
    }
  }
};
```

When I log the object 'selectPart'  it has the correct fields but assigning these fields into the object 'items' results in 'undefined' values

I must be doing something wrong with scope but I don't know what is wrong.

Please suggest how I can copy fields with this Component

Thanks
[image]

Comment: If `selectPart` is the result of `Array.prototype.filter()`, won't it be an array?

Comment: No. console.log(selectPart) returns an object as expected

Comment: I'm not so sure about that and cannot see any `console.log(selectPart)`. I say it's an array which is why `selectPart.Description` is `undefined`

Comment: I added the console.log(selectPart) while debugging   `Code: "CS-KVM-8P"
Cost: 1688.37
Description: "INTEGRATED DIGITAL 8-PORT KVM OVER IP SWITCH"
Price: 8410
_id: "5d9eb36a9814894c5cea8f83"`  looks like an object

Comment: Looks like a bunch of strings. Can you post a screenshot of your console?

Comment: perhaps you are correct. I assumed that this is an object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200686/discussion-between-des-albert-and-phil).

Comment: See the square brackets on the first line... `[{...}]`. It's an array

Comment: Thanks very much. Your suggestions solved my problem. Many thanks to Phil for helping to understand that 'selectPart' returned by 'filter()' is an array and to Daniel for explaining that the data fields should be declared completely.  The $set method also works as stated but it is simpler to just declare the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more elegant solution to the problem.

Replace .filter() with .find()

```
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Add Item</h4>
    <form @submit.prevent="addItem(item.Code)">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ItemCode">Code</label>&nbsp;
            <select
              id="ItemCode"
              v-model="item.Code"
            >
              <input
                v-model="item.Code"
                type="hidden"
              >
              <option
                v-for="part in PartCodes"
                :key="part"
              >
                {{ part }}
              </option>
            </select>
   .
   .
   .
    </form>
  </div>
```

where the data is

```
  data() {
    return {
      item: {          
          Code: null,
          Description: null,
          Group: null,
          GroupCount: null,
          Quantity: null,
          ExtQuantity: null,
          Cost: null,
          Price: null,
          QuoteNumber: null},
      parts: [],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    PartCodes: function () {
      return [...new Set(this.parts.map(p => p.Code))];
    },
  },
  created() {
    let uri = '/parts';
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      uri = 'http://localhost:4000/parts';
    }
    this.axios.get(uri).then(response => {
      this.parts = response.data;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    addItem(selectCode) {
      let uri = '/items/create';
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        uri = 'http://localhost:4000/items/create';
      }
      let selectPart = this.parts.find( obj => {
        return obj.Code === selectCode;
      });

      this.item.Description = selectPart.Description;
      this.item.Cost = selectPart.Cost;
      this.item.Price = selectPar.Price;

      this.axios.post(uri, this.item)
        .then(() => {
          this.$router.push({name: 'QuoteIndex'});
        });
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

In Vue 2.x, [properties added to objects are not reactive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). You have declared the `item` data item without the properties `Description` and `Price`, and have later assigned these properties using simple object assignment, which Vue will not be able to track.

There are two ways to solve this:

**[1. Declare all reactive properties upfront](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties)**

Change `data` to

```js
data() {
    return {
      item: {
        Description: null,
        Price: null
      },
      parts: [],
    };
  },
```

**[2. Use Vue.set()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)**

Change

```js
this.item.Description = selectPart.Description;
this.item.Price = selectPart.Price;
```

to

```js
this.$set(this.item, 'Description', selectPart.Description);
this.$set(this.item, 'Price', selectPart.Price);
```

Thankfully [in Vue 3.x this caveat will be eliminated](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/plans-for-the-next-iteration-of-vue-js-777ffea6fabf) and all properties added to reactive objects will themselves become reactive.

Comment: OP could also just use `this.item = { Description: selectPart.Description, Price: selectPart.Price }` which will be reactive